# Unable to loop through string array and append to FormData

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a file upload module in AngularJS. I will be having multiple file controls and each control can upload one file at a time (not multiple). Finally on click of submit I am saving all the files. I am dynamically generating file controls using `ng-repeat` as below.

```html
 <div class="upload-button" ng-repeat="fileInput in fileInputs">
                <div class="upload-button-icon">
                    <img src="images/folder-small.png">
                    <div class="upload-text">{{fileInput}}</div>
                    <input type="file" file-data="{{fileInput}}" file-model="{{fileInput}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS code to assign values to file controls

```
$scope.fileInputs = ["Passport","Visa"];
```

Below is my code to upload files.

```
myapp.factory('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var fileuploadurl = "http://localhost:19144/" + 'api/Customer/UploadLeaseFiles/' + 2;
    var service = {
        uploadUrl: fileuploadurl,
        pendingFiles: [],
        doUpload: doUpload
    };
    return service;
    function doUpload() {
        debugger;
        var files = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(this.pendingFiles, function (value, index) {
            files.append('file', value);
            files.append('IndexValue', index);

        });
        return $http.post(this.uploadUrl, files, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
    }
}]);
```

This is my directive code.

```
myapp.directive('fileModel', ['fileUpload', function (fileUpload) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("change", function (evt) {
                fileUpload.pendingFiles[attrs.fileModel] = evt.target.files[0];
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Above code will work only if I assign integers to fileInputs as:

```
$scope.fileInputs = [1,2,3];
```

I am struggling to understand why it is working if I assign integer to fileinputs. How can I assign strings and make the above code work?

Comment: You are trying to access `pendingFiles`. Where are you defining it ?

Comment: Thankyou. Yeah. Please see directive  fileModel. It takes files.

Comment: Not sure if I got you yet.  What is the `fileUpload` injected in to the directive

Comment: Hey, you are trying to put files in an array. So with number it will work fine because numbers can be indexex. You can't just make string an index

Comment: Oh thank you. Is there any alternatives solution to fix this? I will get $scope.fileInputs = ["Passport","Visa"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing files in an array. Basically you are doing something like:

```
pendingFiles[1] = file
```

and again

```
pendingFiles["passport"] = file
```

The first case works fine with array, but the second won't.

So the solution is change pending files to an object like:

```
var service = {
        uploadUrl: fileuploadurl,
        pendingFiles: {},
        doUpload: doUpload
    };
```

With object you can make properties on it like:

```
{
passport : file,
Visa : file2
}
```

and then use this object while you upload.

**Update**

for sending extra data use data property of formData obj. Like:

```
 var files = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(this.pendingFiles, function (value, index) {
            files.append('file', value);
            files.append('IndexValue', index);
            files.append ('data', angular.toJson(anyJSObject));

        });
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Is there any way that i can send one extra parameter to api call files.append('file', value);
            files.append('IndexValue', index);

Comment: That should be possible. Since you are using `FormData` you can send any data you want

Comment: Thanks and it is working. How can i retrieve this    files.append ('data', angular.toJson(anyJSObject));
in web api?

Comment: In your api controller method, you should be getting it like : `var data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["data"];`

Comment: you helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: Glad,  I could. :)