# FormData append not working with $http post

Tags: angularjs, multipartform-data

I want to submit info to an online server and it requires that I send that using FormData.
So I am using the following function for that

```
var my_app = angular.module("my-app",[])
my_app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.master = {title: "Title",desc: "Desctibe", tags: ["One","Two"], category: ["1","2"] };
    var url = "http://freedoctor.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/api/forum/create";
    var config = {"headers":{"Authorization":"JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjU5MzEwNDUxZjk3MjJmZTQyODE1NTIxYSIsInJvbGUiOiJwYXRpZW50IiwiaWF0IjoxNDk3NDE4ODA3fQ.ODrSlYwxvrPb93IzHW3s-7NIVFsOL4pKzqZx8yMqWWE"}};

    $scope.booking = function(){
        $scope.title=$scope.user.title;
        $scope.desc=$scope.user.desc;
        $scope.tags=$scope.user.tags;
        $scope.category=$scope.user.category;
        $scope.askedTo=$scope.user.askedTo;
        var info = new FormData();
        info.append("title", $scope.title);
        info.append("desc", $scope.desc);
        info.append("tags", $scope.tags);
        info.append("category", $scope.category);


        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/"+url, info, config).then(
        function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.reply = response.data;
            },
            function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $scope.reply = response.data;
            });
    }

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
});
```

So whenever I call booking function I get an internal server error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
at parse (/home/freedoctor/fdhbackend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
at /home/freedoctor/fdhbackend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (/home/freedoctor/fdhbackend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
at done (/home/freedoctor/fdhbackend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/freedoctor/fdhbackend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

I know the FormData is working as i checked it out with this

```
for (var pair of info.entries()) {
  console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The additional data that you are trying to pass along the formData object should be appended to the `data` property of the `FormData` Object. I once wrote the following function. Should work for you too:

```
this.uploadFile = function (url, dataToUpload) {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("file", dataToUpload.file); //if you want to upload files along, else ignore this line
            data.append("data", angular.toJson(dataToUpload.data)); //you can pass an object containing additional data and then append it here to the data property
            return $http.post(url, data, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            });
        }
```

You can chain your `.then` callbacks to the returned object from this function.

Try this and update if you face any issue.

Comment: I answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405200/unable-to-loop-through-string-array-and-append-to-formdata/44405713#44405713.  May be you can relate to it somehow

Comment: Thanks for answering but i dont think this will work in my case. As i want to send strings only in the request.

I just cant understand the error I receive after I make the call

Comment: I see you are trying to add custom properties to the `FormData` obj. I doubt that is not supported and hence your request fails to be serialized.